# Is it possible to create a continuously looping video?

Tags: mp4, mpeg, avi

Is is possible to create a continuously looping video? Maybe by editing the container it's in so that it restarts automatically?

I have a demonstration video that is playing on a TV in the lobby of our offices. The video is being played by the the smart functionality of the TV. The TV unfortunately doesn't include any kind of looping capability. My current solution has been to concat the video so it is one longer video but it would be nice to not have to go and restart the video every hour.

The file format that can be played is fairly flexible.

Comment: Not aware of a video file format which can encode that info (and more importantly, a player that can execute it). How about a media player with repeat function, like this one: http://www.asus.com/us/Home-Entertainment/OPlay_Mini/ ?

Comment: Some players will just loop if they reach the end of the content, yours doesn't appear to. Some players will only loop if the content is called "CONTINUE LOOP.AVI" It might be a long shot but worth a go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make similar videos for our corporate reception, interstate and overseas offices, events, conferences and presentations etc. The answer is to look outside the video file itself and focus on the application that is playing the file - you want the application to loop the video file playback.

An alternative approach that works on some devices is to embed the single instance of the video file in a PDF and set the playback preferences of the PDF viewer to loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the raspberry pi zero for this.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/

It costs £4 and has an HDMI Output that feeds into most TVs. Using https://osmc.tv/ (formerly  raspbmc) you could loop a video file forever and have it boot automatically when it powers up

Answer (score 1):

Use a DVD authoring program. For example, Adobe Encore to create a VOB (MPEG2) DVD file. Most media players recognize this format. In the authoring software, you can make the movie autoloop, so the movie will always loop even after you shut down the system and restart it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to embed the video in a simple webpage you could use the HTML5 [video player loop](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp) option:

```
<video loop="loop"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it and open it with movies and tv, then select the 3 dots toolbar in the lower right corner and you should see a option called repeat!

Comment: You need to give some more info in your answer. You should probably mention that this solution is limited to Windows 8 & 10.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, if you upload to Youtube and as it's playing, right click and choose loop.
Needs to be done for each launch b

Answer (score -1):

Band aid solution - when it's playing in Quicktime, go to 'view' and you can loop it from there. It'll loop for as long as the file is open, albeit with a minor 'hiccup' at the end of the loop.

Comment: The OP is using a smart TV, not quicktime.  I'm not sure how this is going to help them.